# Variable 'std' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, error-handling

Why I'm gettin this kind of error. I have been practising with respect to tutorial but still I get  this. how should clear this error. I have started to practice .net. so please guide  me

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim std As DataSet1TableAdapters.studentTableAdapter

    If txtname.Text = "" Then
        lblMessage.Text = "Please enter name"
    ElseIf txtclass.Text = "" Then
        lblMessage.Text = "Please enter class "
    ElseIf txtsemseter.Text = "" Then
        lblMessage.Text = "Please enter semester"
    Else
        std.Insert(Name:=txtname.Text, Class:=txtclass.Text, Semester:=txtsemseter.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

link of tutorial:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDFo-nGdUQY

Comment: You'll need to 'new up' the variable before use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do as below

```
Dim std As New DataSet1TableAdapters.studentTableAdapter()
```

when you call `std.Insert` you need to have object of `DataSet1TableAdapters.studentTableAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to new up the variable, as in:

```
Dim std As New DataSet1TableAdapters.studentTableAdapter()
```

Edit: I was trying to do this on a phone, not easy :)

Comment: Ironically (or maybe just amusingly) you missed the keyword `new` in your code sample...

Comment: I was trying to do this on a phone...having a nightmare with that! :)